# Allow function to directly change the elements of the input

Tags: c++, function, pointers, input, binary-search-tree

I have the following class

```
template<class ItemType>
class BSTree
{
    public:
    BSTNode* root=NULL;
    BSTree(); //default constructor
    void insert(BSTNode* temproot,address toin); //insert node
    void delet(address searchkey); //delete a node that matches the given search key
    bool search(address searchkey); //check if the searched node is in the tree, has two inputs so the search can be done recursively
    BSTNode* getRef(BSTNode *temproot, address searchkey); //return a pointer of the searched node if it's in the tree
    int size(); //return the size of the tree
    bool isEmpty(); //check if the tree is empty
    void emptyBook(); //make the entire tree empty

    void inorder(BSTNode *temproot);//traversing the tree inorder and print out the elements
};
```

And here's how the insert function is implemented

```
template<class ItemType>
void BSTree<ItemType>::insert(BSTNode* temproot, address toin)
{
    if(temproot == NULL) //if it's an empty tree, set the new node as the root
    {
        printf("Setting Root\n");
        temproot=new BSTNode;
        temproot->key = toin;
        temproot->left = NULL;
        temproot->right = NULL;
        temproot->parent = NULL;
        root=temproot; //this line DOES NOT WORK with more than one nodes in the tree

        return;
    }
    else if(toin.firstName>temproot->key.firstName)
    {
        printf("Traveling right\n");
        insert(temproot->right, toin); //recur down the right
        temproot->right->parent = temproot; //set the parent of the child
        temproot->right=getRef(root,toin); //set the child of the parent
    }
    else if(toin.firstName<temproot->key.firstName)
    {
        printf("Traveling left\n");
        insert(temproot->left, toin); //recur down the left
        temproot->left->parent = temproot; //set the parent of the child
        temproot->left=getRef(root,toin); //set the child of the parent
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return;
    }
}
```

It currently only works for one input, if I want to insert a second item into the tree the entire thing falls apart. Is there a way for me to directly modify certain element of the tree just by changing the temproot variable in the function? So I don't have to do the root=temproot thing?

Below is the node structure and the address structure

```
struct BSTNode //each node stores the element and three pointers to the left/right and parents if the node
{
    address key;
    BSTNode *left;
    BSTNode *right;
    BSTNode *parent;//used to identify the root
};

class address
{
    public:
    std::vector<char> firstName;
    std::vector<char> lastName;
    std::vector<char> street;
    std::vector<char> city;
    std::vector<char> state;
    long int zipCode; //zip codes are usually short enough to be stored as int, but to be safe long int is used
    long long int phone; //to hold a phone number, more bits are required
    void setAddress(char firstName[],char lastName[],char street[],char city[], char state[], long int zipCode, long long int phone); //initialize a single address
    void printAddress(); //print out the address and all its information, mainly for testing
};
```

I'm thinking there might be some tricks I can do with pass by value/pointer/address but have no clue how to go about doing it

Comment: You have a `tree`.  It's methods include inserting a `node`.  That's where your logic falls apart.  Look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insert-operation-in-b-tree/

Comment: When you design your class you have to think about the class from the users point of view. What does the user want to insert into the tree? Obviously an address, so that should be the only parameter to the insert method. temproot is no use at all. Implement your insert method without it.